# How to recover MobileFirst7.1 Analytics data

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

While setting up the time to live values we got our analytics data deleted. How can we recover that data? We do have the backup of analyticsData folder from the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once the system purges the data (using the TTL Settings), it is not possible to recover the data. 
If you have the backup of the server, perform the following

1. Login to the Operational Analytics Console
2. Remove the TTL Settings
3. Stop the Analytics Server
4. Copy the analyticsData directory from the backup to the right
   location on analytics Server
5. Restart the server